# How can you apply a named scope to Tire search results?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, scope, elasticsearch, tire

I'm using the Tire gem to integrate Elasticsearch into my app, but it throws an error when I try to apply my named scope to it:

```
scope :unflagged, -> { where('flags_count < 4') }


def self.search(params)
  tire.search(page: params[:page], per_page: 12) do
        query { string params[:query], default_operator: "AND" } if params[:query].present?   
    sort { by :unflagged } if params[:query].blank?
     end
end
```

Error:

```
400 : {"error":"SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query], all shards failed; shardFailures {[JDdrV2g5RWiePD6SezSHvQ][posts][1]: SearchParseException[[posts][1]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{\"sort\":[\"unflagged\"],\"size\":12}]]]; nested: SearchParseException[[posts][1]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [No mapping found for [unflagged] in order to sort on]]; }{[JDdrV2g5RWiePD6SezSHvQ][posts][2]: SearchParseException[[posts][2]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{\"sort\":[\"unflagged\"],\"size\":12}]]]; nested: SearchParseException[[posts][2]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [No mapping found for [unflagged] in order to sort on]]; }{[JDdrV2g5RWiePD6SezSHvQ][posts][0]: SearchParseException[[posts][0]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{\"sort\":[\"unflagged\"],\"size\":12}]]]; nested: SearchParseException[[posts][0]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [No mapping found for [unflagged] in order to sort on]]; }{[JDdrV2g5RWiePD6SezSHvQ][posts][4]: SearchParseException[[posts][4]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{\"sort\":[\"unflagged\"],\"size\":12}]]]; nested: SearchParseException[[posts][4]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [No mapping found for [unflagged] in order to sort on]]; }{[JDdrV2g5RWiePD6SezSHvQ][posts][3]: SearchParseException[[posts][3]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{\"sort\":[\"unflagged\"],\"size\":12}]]]; nested: SearchParseException[[posts][3]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [No mapping found for [unflagged] in order to sort on]]; }]","status":400}
```

I've seen a couple of similar questions posted on SO, but never with an answer.

Could anyone explain if it's possible to apply a named scope to Tire/Elasticsearch?  And if so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure this qualifies as an 'answer', but being completely stumped and seeing there were several similar unanswered questions about scopes and Tire on SO, I would recommend anyone else having the same issues to simply use another search client.

My criteria were that it had a free tier production support on Heroku, was relatively easy to implement with good documentation, and supported my existing scopes.

I have gone with Swiftype, which meets all those criteria, providing excellent [documentation](https://swiftype.com/documentation/tutorials/rails), a sample [app](https://github.com/swiftype/swiftype-rails-example), and a [free tier](https://addons.heroku.com/swiftype#starter) on heroku.